# Bootstrap gallery showing pictures from remote ftp location

Tags: vb.net, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

Would like to take your advice as i am going to create pictures gallery which would be showing pictures located on some ftp location. I just started and what i did so far i pass ftp paths to my view from controller.

This is my controller:

```
   Function Details(Optional ByVal id As Long = Nothing) As ActionResult
        Dim PicsTrans As List(Of tblTransPics) = db.tblTransPics.Where(Function(f) f.IdTrans = id).ToList

        Return View(PicsTrans)
    End Function
```

this is View:

```
@ModelType IEnumerable(Of mymodel.tblTransPics)

@Code
    ViewData("Title") = "Details"
End Code

<h2>Pictures:</h2>

@For Each item In Model
    Dim currentItem = item.PicturePath
    @<tr>
    <td>@currentItem</td>
    </tr>
Next
```

as you see into my view i am passing all ftp paths eg:

```
/trackpictures/image1.jpg
/trackpictures/image2.jpg
/trackpictures/image3.jpg
```

The question is how to initiate ftp connection and instead of paths show the pictures - best would be using bootstrap gallery. **But most important thing is how to show the pictures from ftp?**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure your going to get a browser to do that reliable

I would either host the pictures on a Web server on download them in your controller and return the images instead of the path

Comment: coulb be that controller based on given paths would connect to ftp location would take images based on specified paths - download somwhere to local temp directories and pass it to view where e.g bootstrap gallery would show them. Is it reliable scenario? whether pictures has to be firstly downloaded locally?

Comment: Yeah that would work ... but you don't need to store the picture, you can just return the bytes encoded in base 64